# Not able to print the duplicate characters present in a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was trying to print a duplicate character present in a string.

There is a string a="ctintcdctccc" .I wrote a nested while loop to check if the first index of the string 'a' is equal to the second index of  'a' . I was trying to check  by  taking two parameters i and j keeping the value of i initially equal to 0 but the value of j loops from 0 to the string length-1 so it compares the everytime each index of the string with the next index of the  string and prints the duplicate value.

```
a="ctintcdctccc"  
i=0
j=0
char=""
while i<len(a)-1:
    while j<len(a)-1:
        if a[i]==a[j+1]:
            char=char+a[i]
        j+=1
    i+=1
print(char)
```

The output I am getting is char=ccccc but not printing other duplicate string 't' which is also a duplicate value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why your algorithm doesn't work is you never reset the value of *j* after the first iteration.
Thus, what you wanted to do is certainly:

```py
a = "ctintcdctccc"
i = 0
j = 0
char = ""
while i < len(a)-1:
    j = i+1  # reset j
    while j < len(a)-1:
        if a[i] == a[j+1]:
            char = char+a[i]
        j += 1
    i += 1

print(char) # 'cccctttccccc'
```

Which still fails to do what you wanted.

A more simple (draft) solution is:

```py
char = {}
for i in a:
    if i in char:
        char[i] += 1
    else:
        char[i] = 1
print(char)   # char = {'c': 6, 't': 3, 'i': 1, 'n': 1, 'd': 1}
```

Alternatively
You can use [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html) to do that:

```py
from collections import Counter

a="ctintcdctccc" 
b = Counter(a)  # b = {'c': 6, 't': 3, 'i': 1, 'n': 1, 'd': 1}
```

Comment: How do we get the result without implementing Counter and could you explain what is wrong in my code?

Comment: I dont get it . Even if i didnt initialise j=i+1 the value of j was geting incremented by 1 by (j+=1 statement) rt?

Comment: @user11582315 This is true only for the first iteration (i =0), when *i* reach the next value, *j* value is 10 and the instructions after `while j < len(a)-1` are never reached because the condition is false.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, your *j* is not getting reset. So, your loops are only getting executed once. Do reset *j* as *j=i* before the inner loop starts. Plus you can check if the element is already present in the *char* string.

```
while i<len(a)-1:
    j = i
    while j<len(a)-1:
        if a[i]==a[j+1]:
            if(a[i] not in char):
                char=char+a[i]
        j+=1
    i+=1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could change it into a list and then use `count()` and `remove()`:

```
a="ctintcdctccc"  
a = list(a)
i = 0
dups = ''
while a:
    if a.count(a[i])>1:
        dups += a[i]*a.count(a[i])
    temp = a[i]
    for o in range(a.count(a[i])):
        a.remove(temp)
print(dups)
```

That way, you don't need to import anything, and it will work on any computer with python.

Alternatively, you could fix you code to reset `j` at the start of each iteration of your first `while` loop